# Algebro-geometric construction of ramified Donaldson invariants

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

I would like to know if people have constructed an algebro-geometric description or interpretation of the ramified [Donaldson invariants of Kronheimer and Mrowka](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214456482) in the same spirit of Li, [see for example here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214453683).

The ramified Donaldson invariants are defined for smooth four-manifolds $X$ with an embedded complex surface $S$. Then the ramified Donaldson invariants are defined in terms of a the moduli space $M$ of ramified instantons defined over $X \backslash S$. For more details see the first reference but roughly they are integrals of differential forms over $M$.